# What will be the value in the below cases?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-to-array

If I define an array `arr[]` and define a pointer to it:

```
int *p=arr;
```

If the value of `arr` (in terms of address) is `0x1234`. What will be the value of `p`? Will it be the same?

Comment: You can (extremely) easily check this.

Comment: Yes you can: `printf("%p", p);`

Comment: @cst Respect yourself and respect others, calm down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The value is the same.
To check this, just try

```
printf("arr=%p p=%p\n", arr, p);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `p` will be same as that of `arr`.

Reason: the name of the array represents the base address and you are assigning that to pointer `p`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check things like variable values easly using printf function or the  [gdb](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger.

Here is how to solve your problem with gdb :

```
gdb a.out //you must have compile with -g
b main.c:10 //place a breakpoint at the 10th line of main.c, in this case 10 is arbitrary it just need to be after your variable assignement
r //run
p &arr //print the address of arr
p p //print the value of p
p p == &arr //print 1 if p == &arr
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of p will be the same.
If we assume as you said that the value of arr is **0x1234**,the pointer p will take the same value.This because pointer p has enough space to keep the address of the arr array...

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
int *p = arr;
```

*The values of `arr` and `p` are the same.*

But values are just a part of variables. Variables are composed of values and types. The types of `arr` and `p` are different.

You might like to read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The "value of `arr`" is not an address. `arr` is a variable of array type, and its "value" is an array, i.e. a sequence of `int` elements. "Value" is only meaningful in the context of a type.

An expression of array type (e.g. `arr`) can be implicitly converted to an rvalue expression of pointer type (with the value being the address of the first element of the array) in contexts that want a pointer type. `int *p=arr;` is such a context.

Answer (score -2):

An array name is a pointer to first element of it. For example:

```
int a[5];
```

then,

> a

is an int * which points to element a[0]. If the value of arr is

> 0x1234

the value of p will be the same. But be careful about access to array with p(array range should be considered).

Comment: You should be careful in both cases. Nobody checks array bounds even when accessing through array.